# WPF Mainwindow closed automatically after refresh the child Usercontrol inside mainwindow

Tags: wpf, xaml, showdialog

I am developing WPF application which contains MainWindow.xaml as container to display all user controls inside the Mainwindow .I have defined all the menus inside the Mainwindow.xaml and displaying the respective usercontol inside mainwindow.xaml grid.

Below is my Mainwindow grid definition and respective codebehind event handler code

```
<Grid x:Name="Container" Grid.Column="0"  Width="0" Margin="0,0,0,10" Visibility="Visible">           
</Grid>
```

Code Behind Menu click Event Handler

When the maindow is loaded after login it will call and display the CustomerListView user control

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    CustomerListView CLView = new CustomerListView ();
    Container.Children.Clear();
    Container.Children.Add(CLView );
    Container.Children[0].SetValue(WidthProperty, CLView.Width);
    Container.Children[0].SetValue(HeightProperty, CLView.Height);    
}
```

//Customer Menu Click Event

```
public void NewCustomer_Menu_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //AddCustomer is User control
    AddCustomer AddEmployeeObject = new AddCustomer();

    Container.Children.Clear();
    Container.Children.Add(AddEmployeeObject);
    Container.Children[0].SetValue(WidthProperty, AddEmployeeObject.Width);
    Container.Children[0].SetValue(HeightProperty, AddEmployeeObject.Height);
}
```

Everything works fine until i integrate my application by new login control.After successful login i displayed mainwindow. If i am doing some actions like adding new customers(separate user control) or editing new customers(seperate user control) my application get closed automatically.How to overcome this issue?

Code to display mainwinow after logged in

```
if (IsValidUser)//Bool variable to validate user
{
    //Hide the Loginwindow
    this.Hide();
    //Display mainwindow
    MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
    objMainWindow.ShowDialog();               
}
```

If i do any update or insert operations it closes the application after insert or update or refresh.
It seems every time Maindow is reloads after the insert or update or trying to load another user control or refresh the user control inside the mainwindow grid.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woha !!! Got the solution finally. I have defined the button with IsCancel="True" property.So when ever i submit the data it closes the Mainwindow.It's just the copy paste mistake and finally removed the IsCancel attribute and works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are clearing your `Grid` named Container every time you add a new Customer object by calling `Container.Children.Clear()`. Don't add new controls in code behind, instead define your UI in XAML and use data binding to visualize the objects you are adding.

Some links for you to read:

Data Binding Overview: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx
ObservableCollection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Roel.I have lots of user control in my application.I could not define all in Mainwindow page.I need any temporary solutions to resolve this.